# Building z3 on mac os x

Tags: build, z3

I'm trying to build [Z3](http://z3.codeplex.com/releases/view/95640) on mac os x.

Following README file, I just executed

```
autoconf
./configure
make
```

to get an error "omp.h" file not found.

I copied the omp.h file from `/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/include` to `lib` directory to solve this issue.

Then, I got `lib/buffer.h:243:13: error: use of undeclared identifier 'push_back'` error in building the code.

What could be the solution? I have `gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)` on Mac OS X 10.7.5.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The next release (Z3 v4.3.2) will have better support for OSX, clang, and older versions of gcc. 
You should be able to compile the release candidate using the following instructions. `rc` is the branch that contains the current release candidate.

```
git clone https://git01.codeplex.com/z3 -b rc
cd z3
python scripts/mk_make.py
cd build
make
```

BTW, the link http://z3.codeplex.com/releases/view/95640 does not contain the latest release (Z3 v4.3.1). We don't create zip files with source code anymore because codeplex automatically generates them for any version. See [this link](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/leonardo/blog/2012/11/11/reorg-z3.html) for additional details.

**EDIT**
on February 2013, we started to provide nightly builds for all major platforms (including OSX). [Here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/leonardo/blog/2013/02/15/precompiled.html) are instruction on how to download these pre-compiled binaries.
**END EDIT**

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/):

```
> brew install z3
```