# Cannot install z3 package for Haskell on OS X

Tags: haskell, z3, haskell-stack

I'm trying to install the [z3](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/z3) package as follows:

```
stack install z3 --extra-lib-dirs=/usr/local/bin --extra-include-dirs=/usr/local/bin
```

Which brings up the following errors:

```
Configuring z3-4.3.1...
Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_2.2.0.1_ghc-8.4.3: Missing dependency on a foreign
library:
* Missing (or bad) header file: z3.h
* Missing (or bad) C library: z3
This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags
--extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.If the
library file does exist, it may contain errors that are caught by the C
compiler at the preprocessing stage. In this case you can re-run configure
with the verbosity flag -v3 to see the error messages.
If the header file does exist, it may contain errors that are caught by the C
compiler at the preprocessing stage. In this case you can re-run configure
with the verbosity flag -v3 to see the error messages.
```

I originally installed z3 as so:

```
brew install z3
```

and verified the installation location by running

```
which z3 #=> /usr/local/bin/z3
```

Let me know what I could try!

Comment: Does the `z3` module also installs *header* files, etc.?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - not sure, should I try compiling from source instead?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Trying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130739/building-z3-on-mac-os-x) now.

Comment: In Debian/Ubuntu, the header-containing packages are generally called `lib-dev`, i.e. in this case `libz3-dev`. Don't know about homebrew, but might be similar.

Comment: @leftaroundabout didn't find `libz3-dev` or `z3-dev` to work unfortunately.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem tried installing from source and that didn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably need to pass `--extra-lib-dirs=/usr/local/lib --extra-include-dirs=/usr/local/include`.

Comment: Thanks, the following `stack.yaml` config worked:

extra-include-dirs:
  - /usr/local/include
extra-lib-dirs:
  - /usr/local/lib
extra-deps:
- z3-4.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Actually I already spent 2 days with this. So I decide to use VM Ubuntu. I suggest VM who are using M1-M2 Macbook. Right now everything is working for me.

Install z3 by entering the following commands in the terminal:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install z3
```

And if will you get LLVM error : https://apt.llvm.org/

But if you want to continue with OS X firstly run

```
brew install z3
```

and also add these in stack.yaml

```
extra-include-dirs:
- /opt/homebrew/opt/23/include
extra-lib-dirs:
- /opt/homebrew/opt/z3/lib
```